# Why did Biden say "the count works"?

Tags: nouns

Why did Biden say "the count works" when he referred to votes?

Why not "the *counting* works"?

Is the second one wrong?

Comment: Also, American politicians need to communicate in very short "sound bites", if they want to be accurately quoted by television reporters.  This means that politicians' most-widely reported statements are more like slogans or headlines than comprehensive statements.

Comment: "Count" can be a noun, e.g. "Give me a count of the bottles on the shelf." [The Count can also be a proper noun: see on Sesame Street.]

Comment: The noun _count_ is the word normally used for the process of counting votes in an election.